# showing result of try except integer check as a string

Tags: string, exception, python-3.x

I need a function to check that different user input variables are integers.
The results should be confirmed to the user at the end.
The check works in that it keeps looping until integer is typed in, 
but cannot get the results to display...

```
def chkint(msg):
    while True:
        try:
            n = input(msg)
            return(int(n))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter an actual integer.")


number1 = input (chkint("Please enter first value:"))

number2 = input (chkint("Please enter second value:"))

results = (number1, number2)

print ("I have accepted: " + str (results))
```

Comment: What display do you want? "I have accepted: " followed by 2 numbers, or to track the exception text as your question suggests?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I want it to display the two imputed numbers.
I'm not 100% sure on the logic of the function to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer, so I just played about with this and hey presto, it works...

```
def chkint(msg):
    while 1:
        try:
            n = input(msg)
            return(int(n))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter an integer.")

number1 = chkint("Please enter first value:")

number2 = chkint("Please enter second value:")

results = [number1, number2]

print ("I have accepted: " + str (results))
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting it to `int()` in a `try:` block is a good way to check a number.  In your original attempt you were asking for an input whose message relied on further input.

Simplified version of the mistake:

```
def getMessage():
    return input()   # this asks the user what to ask the user for

input(getMessage())  # this waits for getmessage to finish before asking the user
```

Removing the `input()` statements was the easiest fix, as you did.
But a more readable fix would be to make `chkint(msg)` do nothing but return true or false based on whether or not the string was a number, like this

```
def chkint(msg):   # returns true if the string can be converted, false otherwise
    try:
        int(msg)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```